# RIA Services : Include with Select(Many) not Working

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, ria

I have two entity types: `Document` (has a `Customer`) and `Customer` (has a collection `Documents`)

My query is to get documents for a customer based on either the customer's name or number.

The query looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<Document> GetCustomerDocuments(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string filterText)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Customers
              .Where(c => c.CustomerName.Contains(filterText) || c.CustomerNumber.Contains(filterText))
              .SelectMany(c => c.Documents)
              .Where(d => d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate);
}
```

When the query returns, I want it to include BOTH the `Document` and `Customer` entities....

I have tried everything I can think of including `Include("Documents.Customer")`,`Include("Customer")`,etc.

I definitely have the `IncludeAttribute` set in the metadata.

Thoughts?  Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using projection and `SelectMany`, I wrote a LINQ query using a join:

```
        var v = from cust in (from c in this.ObjectContext.Customers
                where  (c.CustomerName.Contains(filterText) || c.CustomerNumber.Contains(filterText))  select c)
                join doc in this.ObjectContext.Documents on cust.CustomerNumber equals doc.CustomerNumber
                where doc.Date >= startDate && doc.Date <= endDate
                select doc;
        return ((ObjectQuery<Document>)v).Include("Customer").AsQueryable<Document>();
```

This solves the problem!

Comment: Absolute life saver and completely non-obvious to cast the query result to ObjectQuery. Please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.Include` works off ObjectQuery, and it's effect will be undone when adding any custom projection. You can try the following options:

Rewrite the query in terms of Document:

```
return this.ObjectContext.Documents.Include("Customers")
          .Where(d => d.Customers.Any(c => 
                                      c.CustomerName.Contains(filterText) 
                                   || c.CustomerNumber.Contains(filterText))
          .Where(d => d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate);
```

This may or may not work, and may or may not generate decent sql; to be tested.

Another possibility is to define a DTO object

```
class CustomerDocument
{
   public Customer {get;set;}
   public Document {get;set;}
}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
return from c in this.ObjectContext.Customers
       from d in c.Documents
       where (c.CustomerName.Contains(filterText) 
          || c.CustomerNumber.Contains(filterText))
           && d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate
       select new CustomerDocument {Customer = c, Document = d};
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was more or less doing it your first way originally, but it ends up being far too slow when I have to go through `Documents` to get to `Customer` so I was trying to do the reverse.  I didn't even think of the DTO object though.  That is a wonderful idea.  (Though that would end up duplicating the Customer info, correct?)

Comment: Probably, yes. Unless the RIA services infrastructure would somehow take care of that, but I doubt it does (you could test that by verifying client-side if 2 customers with the same Id in the returned list are reference equal).